# Joining to a certain property of a composite primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, composite-key

I'm using hibernate, and i have two tables (legacy, they cant be restructured) like the following

Table A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public Class TableA implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId private TableAId tableAId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tableA")
    private TableB tableB;

    // getters, setters, hashCode and equals ommited
}
```

Composite Id of Table A

```
@Embeddable
public class TableAId implements Serializable {
    protected int id1;
    protected String id2;
    protected int id3;
    // getters, setters, hashCode and equals ommited
}
```

Table B

```
@Entity
public class TableB implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableB", referencedColumnName = "id3")
    protected TableA tableA;
    // getters, setters, hashCode and equals ommited
}
```

As can be seen on above code, i need that table B to join table A using one or more (not all) properties of the composite key of the table. I already 've tried with no success, with these three approaches:

1. Exactly like code above.
2. Changing referencedColumnName value like this

   ```
   referencedColumName = "tableAId.id3"
   ```
3. Adding properties that compound the composite key also in the pojo entity of TableA like this:

   ```
   // TableA
   @Column(name = "id1", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Integer id1;
   ```

I if this is even posible??, if it is any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: if I recall I didn't, I probably worked around it

Answer (score 0):

I think the JPA annotation @MapsId might work for you here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html

In TableA class, try this for the tableB property:

```
@MapsId("id3")
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "tableA")
private TableB tableB;
```

Remove the @JoinColumn annotation from the tableA property in TableB class as well.

Comment: I had already checked the annotation you mention, but this is intented to be used when the joining property is in the other table (TableA, not in TableB like in the example)